# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: support, questions

I am referring to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30811/bounty-examples-of-og-privacy-policies-for-various-role-scenarios#comment30593_30811

The same question has been asked by the OP on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1571440), albeit in more detail.

Since it's already been asked on drupal.org, is this question now off topic for this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fine that the same question has been posted on Drupal.org; however, that particular question is actually several questions that are rather vague and likely to invite discussion and also there is an offer of compensation, neither of which I think are inappropriate for *Drupal Answers*.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree :)